# How do I open a file in python?

Tags: python

I need to read the file called, "ranks.dat", however whenever I try opening the file it says there is no such file or directory even though I have downloaded the file. Below is my code:

```
# Reading from a file
numFile = open("ranks.dat", "r")

while True:
    text = numFile.readline()
    #rstrip removes the newline character read at the end of the line
    text = text.rstrip("\n")     
    if text=="": 
        break
    print (text, end = "\t")


numFile.close()
```

The files should always have the following fields:
Rank - Word of Size 15 or less - the Name of the Card
Power - Integer less than 100 - the Power of the Card
Number - Integer less than 100 - the Number of these cards

I need to store each of the fields into their own list. But it does not seem to work.

Comment: I think your program is working as it should. You just need to make the file `ranks.dat` available to the program. Try copying it to the same folder as your script.

Comment: Is the file in the same directory as the script? If not, you need to provide a full path

Comment: @Dallan I am not sure how to put the file in the same directory as the script?

Comment: @quamrana How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the route, here are the lines.

```
import sys
import os

ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
dir = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "YOURFOLDERNAME") 

numFile = open(dir+'/'+"ranks.dat", "r")
```

Comment: If the route is the same as the python file's, it is not necessary.

Comment: @AnnZen so I don't need those two lines?

Comment: That' s true, but maybe have problems with the path, apparently I think he can't find the file and has it inside another folder.

Comment: @kittykat0057 Is your two files in the same folder?

Comment: @AnnZen No, should I put it in the same folder and then try running it?

Comment: @kittykat0057 I believe so.

Comment: yes, try to put it at the same level as your .py --> filenumFile =open(ROOT_DIR+'/'+"ranks.dat", "r"), so you only need ROOT_DIR if you are using same level, otherwise you need yo specify the path using dir = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "your folder name")

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that Python is able to read the path to your file.

```
from os import path

if path.exists('ranks.dat'):
   # do the file processing
else:
   print('Filepath does not exist.')
```

If it prints out that the file path does not exist, then you can provide the full filepath to ranks.dat and it should work.

In addition, you can also use a `context manager` to open and close the file for you when you are done

```
with open('ranks.dat', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
```